# Why does the FTP download not work properly with Java

Tags: java, file, download, ftp, is-empty

i'm currently working on a small checklist builder program in Java. I would like to upload and download the created file to my FTP Server (ftps). I'm using the following code for downloading:

```
public static void downloadfile(){
    FTPSClient con = null;

    System.out.println("Download Status: 5%");
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Download Status: 20%");
        con = new FTPSClient();
        con.connect(url);

        if (con.login(user, psw))
        {
            System.out.println("Download Status: 50%");
            con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
            con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            String data = "E:\\Downloads\\Testdokument.txt";

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(data));
            boolean result = con.retrieveFile("Testdokument.txt", out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println(result);
            if (result) {
                System.out.println("Download Status: 100%");
            } else if(result == false) {
                System.out.println("Download won't work");
            }
            con.logout();
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("download failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

the problem is that the download itself works fine. But the downloaded file is empty. If i try it with an Image it isn't "readable". The upload instead works perfectly. I use the Apache Common IO Library for the FTP function.

If i download the file the console shows first status 5%, 20%, 50% and than, after adding the false statement, Download won't work ...

I have no idea why the file itself is downloading but not including any content.

Any ideas?

Comment: does the local data file exist? does the parent directory exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing resources in java correctly.

Anytime you create an object that represents a resource, you must close it. You open a new `FileOutputStream`, and that is a resource. Anything that implements `AutoCloseable` is definitely a resource that you must close. Try this:

```
try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(data /* no need to wrap in File */)) {
    // do your stuff with out here
}
```

Second note: Your exception handling is atrocious; please stop making this common mistake. Exceptions contain 4 useful bits of information: Type, Message, Trace, and Cause. You're literally tossing 3 out of the 4 into the bin. Just add `throws Exception` to your main method, and your `downloadFile` method. It saves you typing and makes your error messages much more useful.

Comment: ```e.printStackTrace()``` outputs all 4 informations.

Comment: @rzwitserloot thanks to your answer. That's the way i have learned it. But I will remember your hints and try to optimize my code.

Comment: @Stefan no, it does not. Hence the name 'print stack trace': It prints solely the stack trace.

Comment: The printStartTrace outputs all informations, see this: ```java.lang.Exception: something bad happened
 at com.company.Main.doSomething(Main.java:14)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
 at com.company.Main.doSomething(Main.java:10)
 ... 1 more

``` Sorry for the ugly format, I don't know how to format such text in comments.

Comment: @Stefan that is just false. What you're showing is NOT the output of the command `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Of course it is. I created this output a few seconds before with a Java console application that wrote to doublecheck this case. Could it be possible that you are using a special JDK (not Oracle or OpenJDK) which behave differently?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

i have added the following two things and it works now

```
con.execPBSZ(0);
con.execPROT("P");
```

No idea what that stands for, but I'm going to find it out.

Answer (score -1):

I know this answer is off-topic but I like to provide an example for user rzwitserloot which shows that `printStackTrace()` does not hide any important information. This would not fit into a comment:

```
public class Main
{

    public static void doSomething()
    {
        int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
        int b = array[3];  // throws Exception
    }

    public static void test() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            doSomething();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("something bad happened", e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            test();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Produces output:

```
java.lang.Exception: something bad happened
    at Main.test(Main.java:18)
    at Main.main(Main.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
    at Main.doSomething(Main.java:7)
    at Main.test(Main.java:14)
    ... 1 more
```

[image: screenshot of output]

See also the documentation of Oracle:
[image: specification of printStackTrace]

Comment: The code 'e.printStackTrace()' is nowhere in your snippet. We're in vehement agreement: I said to do what you did.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I sent the wrong example. I will fix this... done.